# SharpSvn - Exception from whitespace in path

Tags: sharpsvn

I'm receiving an exception from SharpSvn's client when I try to perform some operations if the specified repository sub-path has a whitespace character in its directory name, ie.

```
https://svn.mycompan​y.com/repos/myteambl​d/MyFolder1/My Folder 2/MyFolder3
```

I am able to access these paths through other applications, and SharpSvn works beautifully with non-whitespaced paths. Also, I am passing the path in as a Uri (not a string), so all spaces are automatically encoded

Here is the exception:

```
SharpSvn.SvnClientUnrelatedResourcesException was caught
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Unable to find repository location for 'https://svn.mycompan​y.com/repos/myteambl​d/MyFolder1/My%20Folder%202/MyFolder3' in revision 496637
  Source=SharpSvn
  Line=0
  OperatingSystemErrorCode=0
  SubversionErrorCode=195012
  StackTrace:
       at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, SvnException error, Object targets) in g:\dist\src\sharpsvn\svnclientargs.cpp:line 78
       at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, svn_error_t* error, Object targets) in g:\dist\src\sharpsvn\svnclientargs.cpp:line 42
       at SharpSvn.SvnClient.InternalLog(ICollection`1 targets, Uri logRoot, SvnRevision altPegRev, SvnLogArgs args, EventHandler`1 logHandler) in g:\dist\src\sharpsvn\commands\log.cpp:line 345
       at SharpSvn.SvnClient.Log(Uri target, SvnLogArgs args, EventHandler`1 logHandler) in g:\dist\src\sharpsvn\commands\log.cpp:line 74
       at SharpSvn.SvnClient.GetLog(Uri target, SvnLogArgs args, Collection`1& logItems) in g:\dist\src\sharpsvn\commands\log.cpp:line 402
```

Answer (score 0):

Spaces aren't valid in URLs. Instead of  you should use `%20`. You can easily encode your URL using [Uri.EscapeUriString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This call:

```
var myUri="https://svn.mycompany.com/repos/myteambld/MyFolder1/My%20Folder%202/MyFolder3";
Uri.EscapeUriString(myUri);
```

will return:

`https://svn.mycompany.com/repos/myteambld/MyFolder1/My%20Folder%202/MyFolder3`

Comment: Good point, but since I am passing the path in as a Uri (as opposed to a string), the spaces are automatically encoded and appear correctly in the exception details. I've updated my question to be more specific, though, so thanks!